# How do you change your minecraft realms world into a single player world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-realms

I know you can turn your single player world into a Minecraft Realm world but how do you do it the other way around?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way for me to Export my Minecraft Realms World?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/252249/is-there-a-way-for-me-to-export-my-minecraft-realms-world)

Answer (score 4):

1. Choose your realm
2. Click "Configure"
3. Click on "World Edit"
4. Click on "Download Latest"

This will give you the world file which you can put with your single player saves.

Answer (score 0):

Well as a young explorer, I thought about that, too.
Thankfully if you go into the .zip file in minecraft, you are able to find .realms. If you click it, you will find 3 folders and an additional .exe.
The 3 folders will be named whatever you put as a name. If you find the one you want, simply drag it to your existing saves in minecraft on files.

Answer (score -1):

You click the wrench then you push world backups, then download latest

Comment: This is basically the same answer as the existing one. Please keep in mind that duplicate answers are frowned upon here and may be subject to deletion.