# Is there a way for me to Export my Minecraft Realms World?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-realms

I have played on my friend's Survival Realm for ~3 months and he was going to stop paying for the realm so I was wondering is there any way to get that world for my Personal Client.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. First, click on the Wrench near on the right of your realm in the realm menu. Next, Click world backup and hit "Download latest." Once you do this, a percentage bar will come up and once you hit 100% you will be able to play the world in singleplayer survival.

Comment: FYI, here's how you export a Realms world in Minecraft Bedrock as of v1.14.30 (tested on iPadOS 13.4). 1.) Make sure you are logged in as the world owner. 2.) Tap Play on the main screen. 3.) Tap the edit/pencil button for the realm. 4.) Make sure the Game option is selected. 5.) On the right side, locate and tap the Download World button. The exported file should be saved in the same location where non-Realm worlds are saved, e.g., .../Minecraft/games/com.mojang/minecraftWorlds/<12-character string>.