# Can I retrieve my Minecraft singleplayer world from Realms when my subscriptions runs out?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-realms

My friend and I would like to buy a 1 month Realm subscription. We would like to upload one of my singleplayer worlds so we can improve it from what it is now. Once the subscription runs out, will I be able to redownload the world ***that includes*** everything we worked on? Or will it just be the old version of the world? If I can redownload the world, how is this done? I am running Minecraft Java Edition on a Windows 10 PC.

Comment: You could start a whitelist server with the single player world.  It is fairly simple to setup, free, and you can go longer then 1 month if you like.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way for me to Export my Minecraft Realms World?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/252249/is-there-a-way-for-me-to-export-my-minecraft-realms-world)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can download your world **before** the subscription ends.

It is all covered on Mojang's help page, [Download Realms World - Java Edition](https://help.mojang.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2313677-download-realms-world---java-edition):

> 1. Go to your Realms configuration by pressing the button with a tool symbol.
> 2. From the Realms configuration screen, go to your "World backups."
> 3. Finally, all you have to do is press the "Download Latest" button and follow the instructions on the screen.
>
> The world you download will be saved with your singleplayer worlds.